# How to get the pure text without HTML element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the 1 button and some text in my HTML like the following:

```
function get_content(){
   // I don't know how to do in here!!!
}

<input type="button" onclick="get_content()" value="Get Content"/>
<p id='txt'>
<span class="A">I am</span>
<span class="B">working in </span>
<span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
```

When the user clicks the button, the content in the `<p id='txt'>` will become the follow expected result:

```
<p id='txt'>
// All the HTML element within the <p> will be disappear
I am working in ABC company.
</p>
```

Can anyone help me how to write the JavaScript function?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[2017-07-25] since this continues to be the accepted answer, despite being a very hacky solution, I'm incorporating [Gabi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376873/gabi-purcaru)'s code into it, leaving my own to serve as a bad example.

```js
// my hacky approach:
function get_content() {
  var html = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
}
// Gabi's elegant approach, but eliminating one unnecessary line of code:
function gabi_content() {
  var element = document.getElementById('txt');
  element.innerHTML = element.innerText || element.textContent;
}
// and exploiting the fact that IDs pollute the window namespace:
function txt_content() {
  txt.innerHTML = txt.innerText || txt.textContent;
}
```

```css
.A {
  background: blue;
}

.B {
  font-style: italic;
}

.C {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="get_content()" value="Get Content (bad)" />
<input type="button" onclick="gabi_content()" value="Get Content (good)" />
<input type="button" onclick="txt_content()" value="Get Content (shortest)" />
<p id='txt'>
  <span class="A">I am</span>
  <span class="B">working in </span>
  <span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Bad because hacky and slow. Is there even a guarantee that the rendered text itself must never contain tags?

Comment: no, there is no such guarantee. I gave a disclaimer when I posted. it apparently served the purpose of the OP.

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regular expressions is really dangerous --- it's practically impossible (I suspect it may be _theoretically_ impossible) to get right. There's too many edge cases and then your code blows up when faced with strange input, which can frequently be exploited to do XSS.

Comment: my guess as to why it was accepted: it's a complete answer, which can be immediately cut-and-pasted as is into an html file and tested with a browser. I never said it was a *good* answer. I posted after seeing all the *good* answers were there, and not accepted, and figured the OP needed a little handholding. it still is good enough for any application for which the HTML source is already known not to contain unbalanced angle brackets.

Answer (score 255):

You can use this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('txt');
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
element.innerHTML = text;
```

Depending on what you need, you can use either `element.innerText` or `element.textContent`. They differ in many ways. [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) tries to approximate what would happen if you would select what you see (rendered html) and copy it to the clipboard, while [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) sort of just strips the html tags and gives you what's left.

`innerText` also has compatability with old IE browsers (came from there).

Comment: +1 - Was looking for some high performance `text` method since it gets done a lot in a loop. jQuery was not performant enough, but this was very fast. Worked in IE8+, chrome, ff. Perfect.

Comment: On old IE, `el.textContent` will be `undefined` and `el.innerText` might be `""`. But `"" || undefined` is `undefined`. Using `el.innerText || el.textContent || ''` may be better.

Comment: innerText doesn't return hidden text and content of script/style tags while textContent does. If you're on a version of IE which supports textContent, it might be preferable to use it first, so `el.textContent || el.innerText || ""`.

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading this answer in present day, more than six years after this answer, these days you can just use `var text = element.textContent;`; unless for some ungodly reason you still have to support [IE8 or below](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: `el.innerText` is roughly the same as `el.textContent.replace(/\W+/g, ' ')`. They are not the same.

Comment: is there a way to do this in node?

Comment: there is a rich html-to-text library for Node

Answer (score 23):

If you can use jquery then its simple

```
$("#txt").text()
```

Comment: I just have to say, look at all the pure JS answers and then look at this one. This is the second most important reason why I use jQuery (i.e., it simplifies tasks, reduces my workload, and increases readability). The first most important reason (to me) is because it handles many cross-compatibility issues, I might otherwise not even be aware of (like using jQuery to adjust opacity, so that I don't have to write a separate line just for IE8 to target the `filter` property. I know that pure JS is technically more efficient when it comes to speed, but that hardly matters anymore in most normal..

Comment: pure js one liner equivalent: `document.querySelector("#txt").innerText;` People include the entire jQuery library far too often when their only need is a couple of lines of code. It's bad practice.

Answer (score 11):

This answer will work to get just the text for any HTML element.

This first parameter "node" is the element to get the text from. The second parameter is optional and if true will add a space between the text within elements if no space would otherwise exist there.

```
function getTextFromNode(node, addSpaces) {
    var i, result, text, child;
    result = '';
    for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        child = node.childNodes[i];
        text = null;
        if (child.nodeType === 1) {
            text = getTextFromNode(child, addSpaces);
        } else if (child.nodeType === 3) {
            text = child.nodeValue;
        }
        if (text) {
            if (addSpaces && /\S$/.test(result) && /^\S/.test(text)) text = ' ' + text;
            result += text;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need, you can use either `element.innerText` or `element.textContent`. They differ in many ways. [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) tries to approximate what would happen if you would select what you see (rendered html) and copy it to the clipboard, while [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) sort of just strips the html tags and gives you what's left.

`innerText` [is not just used for IE anymore](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/), and it is [supported in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=innertext). Of course, unlike `textContent`, it has compatability with old IE browsers (since they came up with it).

Complete example (from [Gabi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743966/5272567)):

```
var element = document.getElementById('txt');
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent; // or element.textContent || element.innerText
element.innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me compiled based on what was said here with a more modern standard. This works best for multiple looks up.

```
let element = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')
  element.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.innerHTML = item.innerText || item.textContent)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
function get_content(){
   var p = document.getElementById("txt");
   var spans = p.getElementsByTagName("span");
   var text = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
       text += spans[i].innerHTML;
   }

   p.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gnyc/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_content(){
 var returnInnerHTML = document.getElementById('A').innerHTML + document.getElementById('B').innerHTML + document.getElementById('A').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = returnInnerHTML;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try (short version of Gabi [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743966/860099) idea)

```
function get_content() {
   txt.innerHTML = txt.textContent;
}
```

```js
function get_content() {
   txt.innerHTML = txt.textContent ;
}
```

```css
span { background: #fbb}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="get_content()" value="Get Content"/>
<p id='txt'>
<span class="A">I am</span>
<span class="B">working in </span>
<span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `I am working in ABC company.` to `I am working in ABC company.`. These are the same strings, so I don't see a reason to, but you can accomplish this by using the JavaScript `innerHTML` or `textContent`.

`element.innerHTML` is a property that defines the HTML inside an element. If you type `element.innerHTML = "<strong>This is bold</strong>`, it'll make the text "This is bold" bold text.

`element.textContent`, on the other hand, sets the text in an element. If you use `element.textContent = "<strong>This is bold</strong>`, The text "This is bold" will not be bold. The user will literally see the text "**This is bold**

In your case, you can use either one. I'll use `.textContent`. The code to change the `<p>` element is below.

```
function get_content(){
   document.getElementById("txt").textContent = "I am working in ABC company.";
}

<input type="button" onclick="get_content()" value="Get Content"/>
<p id='txt'>
<span class="A">I am</span>
<span class="B">working in </span>
<span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
```

This, unfortunately, will not change it because it'll change it to the same exact text. You can chance that by changing the string "I am working in ABC company." to something else.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In John's question, the text: "I am working in ABC company." is just an example, he doesn't want to set the content of the <p> to a "literal string". He doesn't clearly "explicitly" state what he wants, but if you carefully read the question it's clear what he wants. First, he wants a function that will *get* the contents of the <p>: `function get_content()`. and second, he indicates in a `Note/Comment`, that "All the HTML element within the <p> will be disappear". So what he wants, is to get the content of the <p>, so something like `InnerHTML`, --> (continued)

Comment: except he wants all the HTML tags within the content of <p> to be removed. So in the example case, he wants to remove all the <span class="..."> and </span>, and return only the text: "I am working in ABC company.", but in a generalized way so it returns whatever text is actually in <p>. So something like: `var p=document.getElementById("txt"); p.innerHTML=p.textContent;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function get_content() {
        var paragraph = document.getElementById('txt');
        var text = '';

        // Traverse through each child node of the paragraph
        for (var i = 0; i < paragraph.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var node = paragraph.childNodes[i];
            
            // Check if the node is a text node
            if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                // Concatenate the text content of the node
                text += node.textContent;
            }
        }

        // Update the innerHTML of the paragraph with the text content
        paragraph.innerHTML = text;
    }



 <input type="button" onclick="get_content()" value="Get Content"/>
    <p id="txt">
        <span class="A">I am</span>
        <span class="B">working in </span>
        <span class="C">ABC company.</span>
    </p>
```

**Explanation**

This JavaScript function iterates over each child node of the

element. If the node is a text node (i.e., contains only text content), it appends its text content to the text variable. Finally, it sets the innerHTML of the

element to the concatenated text content, effectively removing all HTML tags.