# How to get div text value?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following html:

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="text">
          Blah Blah
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value "Blah Blah" using javascript.

So something like?

```
    alert(document.getElementsByName("question")[0].value);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the pure text without HTML element by javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript) - take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6743966/1456376)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].children[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: It's not great in the general case. If you want just text, use `textContent`.

Comment: @TimDown good to know, but does `textContent` play good with IE?

Comment: It's IE 9+. There's also `innerText` all the way back to IE 4.

Answer (score 7):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('question')[0].innerText;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.question').innerText;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the element correctly first. It doesn't (and can't) have a `name` attribute so `getElementsByName` is wrong. You can use `getElementsByClassName` or (with more limited support) the new and shiny `querySelector`:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.question');
```

Then you need to get it's "value". It isn't a form control so it doesn't have a `value` property. It has childNodes, the one of which you care about is another div.

```
var childDiv = div.querySelector('.text');
```

You can skip the two stages if you are are using querySelector and just use a descendant combinator:

```
var childDiv = document.querySelector('.question .text');
```

This child div then has another child node, but it is a text node rather than an element node. You can get it like so:

```
var textNode = div.firstChild;
```

Finally you can get the text in a textNode using the `data` property.

```
var text = textNode.data;
```

And if you put it all together:

```
alert(document.querySelector('.question .text').firstChild.data);
```

Such: http://jsfiddle.net/LR93S/

Answer (score 2):

No need to rely on jQuery here, use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.question')[0].innerText
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.question').text(); // jquery

 document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].innerText; // javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].innerHTML` (http://jsfiddle.net/hv9Dx/15/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
var divvalue = $('.text').html()
alert (divvalue);
```

You could also change your html to use an ID

```
<div class="question">
<div id="text">
      Blah Blah
</div>
</div>
```

and use:

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/N9Z8Z/

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text')[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard DOM property `textContent`, which is widely supported and standardized, unlike `innerText`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].textContent;
```

If you need to support IE <= 8 then you've got two problems: neither `document.getElementsByClassName()` nor `textContent` is supported.

For the first issue, it's not too hard to write/find a function to retrieve elements by class name using other DOM methods ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie)).

For the second, you can use IE's `innerText` property, which will do roughly ([but not precisely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/96100)) the same thing as `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

For the following example:

```
<div class="question" id="question">
    <div class="text" id="text">
      Blah Blah
    </div>
</div>
```

You can try to get the value of its inner div tag like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('question').childNodes[1].innerHTML);
```

Cheers!