# Retrieving <img> alt value and text in a textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea with this content

```
<textarea id="testContent"> <img src="..." alt="value"> My text.... </textarea>
```

I know I can use javascript to select the alt value of just img tag as shown

```
<script>
    var $textfeldVal = document.getElementById("testContent");
    $img = $textfeldVal.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    alert("ALT VALUE: "+$img.alt);
</script>
```

Is there a way I can use javascript to select the alt value `<img>` along with the text in the textarea?

Comment: again this isn't angularjs.

Comment: This isn't even valid mark-up

Comment: How do you mean @ Stuart Grant. This is a code snippet and as well a code challenge

Comment: Well, I guess it can be considered as valid. But indeed `<textarea>` is only supposed to hold plain text. Not DOM node

Comment: Yeah. At that point the textarea only holds and sees this as text <textarea id="testContent"> <img src="path/value.jpg" alt="value"> My text.... </textarea>

Comment: First, it's not valid html to use an img tag in a textarea. You can check this here: https://validator.w3.org

So you need to put the image into a div tag with`contentEditable="true"`

Second, after that you can get the text value from an element like it is described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript

if you use jQuery you can simply call `$('#testContent).text();`

Comment: You don't have a good picture of the kind of challenge I am facing here. I am not putting <img> tag in a textarea. Just that along the line, I have to retrieve the alt from a text area found in img tag seen as text in a textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you must, you could concatenate them like this:

```
var $textarea = $("textarea#testContent"),
    textareaValue = $textarea.val(),
    // get alt value using regex, as jQuery can't find DOM nodes within a textarea
    altValueMatch = textareaValue.match(/\<img.*?alt=(\"|\')(.*?)\1.*?\>/),
    altValue = (Array.isArray(altValueMatch) && typeof altValueMatch[2] === "string")
        ? altValueMatch[2]
        : null;

// remove the img tag from textareaValue and trim any trailing whitespace
textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(/\<img.*?\>/, "").trim();

var concatenated = [altValue, textareaValue].join(" ");
```

You really shouldn't put DOM nodes inside the textarea though, as it is only designed for plaintext.

Comment: I am only interested in the alt value which is a text value and everything found in a textarea is a text.

Comment: If you only want the alt value, just use the first four variables above, and `altValue` will contain what you want (or be null if no alt attribute exists). As I say, this is a bit of a hacky way of doing it though; ideally, you should never put DOM nodes within a textarea.

Comment: You have making series of updates. Which one I pick. Please show a demo

Comment: @JnG The most recent one (I just added a check so that the variable will be null if no alt attribute exists). This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hot3ofor/) shows it working, it will alert the value of the alt text when you run it.

Comment: What about the content My Text... of the textarea? I want it along with the alt value. Kindly update the output.

Comment: That is shown in the full example above, but you said "I am only interested in the alt value". It seems like your Javascript (and HTML) knowledge is still too low right now, so I suggest you read some books or follow some courses to get a better grasp of things before you embark on a serious project. :) Nonetheless, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/hot3ofor/1/) an updated Fiddle that alerts both values.

Comment: I am doing too many things at thesame. Meanwhile had not studied ur codes critically as you have been updating it now and then :)

Comment: Okay, hope I helped anyway.

Comment: Yeah. Its working! But should incase I insert more than one for instance  <img src="..." alt="show more"/> into the textarea. It fails to return the alt value subsequently. I want to be able as well to return anything alt value in an img as many as possible in the textarea thanks.

Comment: Great, and yes, I'm here now! Here's [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hot3ofor/2/) then that iterates over the image tags and pushes their alt values to an array called `altValues`. As an example, I'm alerting all the values in that array too. Please upvote my answer if this helps, thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Show only one alert holding all the variables

Comment: Yeah, the alerts are just an example, I presume you won't have any in your finished code. You can just replace the `forEach` loop with `alert(altValues)` to alert the entire array (as a string concatenated with commas) at once.

Comment: You are a javascript bad guy :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can put an img tag inside textarea...
Why not simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <img id="imageDiv" src="..." alt="value">
            <div id="textDiv" contentEditable="true"> My text.... </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            var imageDiv = document.getElementById("imageDiv");
            var textDiv = document.getElementById("textDiv");
            alert("ALT VALUE: "+imageDiv.alt+"  "+textDiv.innerHTML);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
In response to @JnG comment:
Then why not just parsing the text:

```
<textarea id="testContent"> <img src="..." alt="value"> My text.... </textarea>

<script>
    var text = document.getElementById("testContent").innerHTML;
    var tmp = text.split("alt=\"")[1];
    var value = tmp.split("\"")[0];
    var myText = tmp.split("\"&gt;")[1];
    alert(value+" "+myText);
</script>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rfhvfwbz/1/

Comment: I am not putting an <img> tag inside a text area. Even a common knowledge shows that they return different values. However, lets just assume that I have a textarea with this strucure <textarea id="testContent"> <img src="..." alt="value"> My text.... </textarea>

Comment: Hope you get now? Or didn't you?

Comment: Sorry yes I got it now, well, I guess ;-).

Comment: Show me a demo. Thanks

Comment: What about the My Text value of the textarea. Want it along side with final output

Comment: The solution fails returning more than one img alt value if necessary