# How to parse text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I get text field in the document. I get it by `Jquery`. 
But sometimes text field includes `<em> </em>` or `<cite> </cite>` tags.
I want the raw text.

I get the text by their id such as; 
`$('title')[0].innerHTML`

It returns me;

```
further cholesterol transport <em class="a-plus-plus"> Large luteal cells </em> produce  <em class="a-plus-plus">more</em>
```

or

```
<cite>Sodium bicarbonate</cite> is a white solid that
```

How can I get the raw text as;

```
further cholesterol transport Large luteal cells produce more

Sodium bicarbonate is a white solid that
```

Should I parse the text when I get by their id, or should write a regex that detects `cite` and `em` tags and gets the text inside these tags. What is the best solution for this problem? Is there any solution offered for this type of parsing?

Comment: `$('title').text().trim()` would be enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery method [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will get the text content of the selector, which will exclude HTML.

```
$('title').text();
```

Similarly in plain JavaScript the [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property will also do this by not parsing as HTML.

```
$('title')[0].textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

A. Wolff is right. Only

```
$(container).text()
```

will work in JQuery.

You can see the reference
[Get the pure text without HTML element by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript)
It is pretty much what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use:

```
$('title').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery

```
$(container).text()
```

Native Javascript

```
document.getElementById('container').innerText.
```