# I can't get Tag content with a Script/Function

Tags: javascript, html

i'm with a ridiculous problem (i think). I just can't get a tag content using a Script/Function/document.getElementById. The alert tha i'm using to see the content of variable (wM) is always blank. I looked a lot of examples in the Web and all of them is similar, sometimes just like my code. See below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang ="pt-br">        
       <head>
          <title> loginServlet2 </title>
          <meta http-equiv = ”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8”>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:/java/html/css/estilo.css"/>    

          <script type="text/javascript">
             function oMsg()
             {
                var wM = document.getElementById("wMsgB").textContent;
//              var wM = document.querySelector("span").textContent;
                alert("wM = "+ wM);

                if (wM == "Teste OK!")
                {
//               document.getElementById("wMsgA").innerHTML = "Test is OK";
                 document.getElementById("wMsgA").textContent = "Test is OK";
                }
                else
                {
                   alert("Test is not OK. Before set new msg");
                   document.getElementById("wMsgA").textContent = "Test is not OK";
                }
             }
          </script> 
       </head>

       <body>
          <h2> Login Page2 </h2>

          <p>Please enter your username and password</p>

          <form method="GET" action="loginServlet2">
             <p id="test2"> Username <input type="text" name="userName" size="50"> </p>

         <p> Password <input type="password" name="password" size="20"> </p>

             <p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" onclick="oMsg()"> </p> 
          </form>

       <h3> MsgB : <span id="wMsgB"<%=request.getAttribute("wMsg")%></span></h3> 


          <p> MsgA : <span id="wMsgA"> </span> </p>

       </body>
    </html>
```

Could anyone help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: Most HTML elements do not have a `value` property.  You might want `textContent`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the pure text without HTML element by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `value` of a `p` element, but `p` elements don't have a `value` property. Only form fields do. Non-form fields that contain text between their opening and closing tags have **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** and **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** properties you can use to get/set their contents.

If you want to give the user a place to type in some data, you need to create some `input` form fields and then you have to wait until they've done that before attempting to get the values.

Next, you have smart quotes `“”` instead of straight quotes `""` which can cause encoding problems. Make sure you write your code in an editor that doesn't apply any formatting to the code. There are plenty of great **[free web editors](https://www.elated.com/articles/10-fantastic-free-web-page-editors/)** out there.

You also have a reference to a `.css` file using a full local path, which isn't going to work when you deploy this code later. You should be using **[relative paths](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)** to reference files that are part of your system.

Finally, you are using some old HTML syntax in your `meta`, `link` and `script` tags, so take note of the modern versions of those in the snippet below.

```html
<head>
      <title>loginServlet2</title>
      <meta charset=UTF-8”>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="c:/java/html/css/estilo.css"/>    

      <script>
         function oMsg() {
            var wM = document.getElementById("wMsg").textContent;
            alert("wM = " + wM);

            if (wM == "Test OK!") {
               document.getElementById("wMsgA").textContent = "Test is OK";
            } else {
               alert("Test is not OK. Before set new msg");
               document.getElementById("wMsgA").textContent = "Test is not OK";
            }
         }
      </script> 
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2> Login Page2 </h2>

      <p>Please enter your username and password</p>

      <form method="GET" action="loginServlet2">
         <p id="test2"> Username <input type="text" name="userName" size="50"> </p>

     <p> Password <input type="password" name="password" size="20"> </p>

         <p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" onclick="oMsg()"> </p> 
      </form>

      <h2>MsgB : <span id="wMsg"><%=request.getAttribute("wMsg")%></span> </h2> 

      <p>MsgA : <span id="wMsgA"> </span> </p>
```

Comment: Scott, actually the code above was simplified only to show it here because i thought that would be possible to get the content (value) of a tag.. My original code is trying to get the answer of a Servlet. Take a look below:                                                                                                
    <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. I've explained (and demonstrated in my answer) how to get the contents of a tag, which is not the same thing as getting the value of a form element. Your question is not marked with Java or references any servlet, but that wouldn't change anything in my answer.

Comment: Scott, sorry. i've tried to respond to you and also to D.Braun but i'v failed.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. Why don't you just edit your question and update it with the code you are using? However, I still don't see how any of that changes my answer.

Comment: Sorry Scott, i'm a newbie here. Now you've my question updated with the full code. You can see now that i wanna call a Servlet, get his answer and use it in the Function oMsg(). You can see that i get the Servlet answer and put it in a tag P (wMsgB). I thought that i could use that tag P to my Function oMsg(), but now i know that is impossible. So, how can i "transfer" de Servlet answer to my Function? Thanks.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. Again, my answer explains what you need. You **can** place the answer into a `p` (actually, you are placing it into a `span` and that's fine too), but you'll need to use `.textContent` to pull the data out, not `.value`. My answer shows this as soon as you run it.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. Look at the last 2 lines in my script.

Comment: Scott, i've made the changes (see my question). Now i've a H2 instead P and i changed  the line with document.querySelector. But, i don't lnow why, i'm still not able to get the Servlet answer into the Function.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. I've updated my answer to use your latest code, but you can't use `.querySelector("h2")` because that gets the first `h2` in the document and that's not the one you want. I have wrapped your `%request...` in a `span` with an `id` and changed the selector to look for that element. Also, your `alert` has a syntax error in it so look at my corrected one.

Comment: Scott, actually the Function received "MsgB : null". I've changed again, including a span (see my question) to leave the response from Servlet isolated from Header tag. And, now, the Function get null.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. I think you need to verify what the servlet is sending back. This really is one of the simplest things you can do and I'm showing you the correct way. You can see from my code snippet when you run it that it does get the PHP code sitting in the `span`. Of course, in your case that `span` would be populated with your servlet's data.

Comment: Scott, my Servlet is answering correctly ("Teste OK!"). I can see that because that answer is copied to wMsgA and is showed perfectly. Also, the first alert is showing null in the wM variable. Ans running the snipped i see in the alert "wM = <%=request.getAttribute("wMsg")%>".

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. I'm sorry. I don't know what else to tell you. I'm showing you a working code solution.

Comment: I'm using Chome. Could be that? I'll try with FireFox and IE.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. No, that would not have any impact. This is standard, simple code that works in all browsers. Have you actually run my code snippet? Did you fix your `alert()` syntax?

Comment: Scott, yes i fixed the alert tag (i've updated my question too). I ran your snippet here, clicking on "Run code snippet" and the Alert showed "wM = <%=request.getAttribute("wMsg")%>. Also, i copied your code and saved an other loginServlet2.jsp and tested it with Chrome. This time the Alert showed "null". The Servlet is running ok because the tag <h2>MsgB : <span id="wMsg"> showed "Teste OK!". Exactly what Servlet returned. Is possible that the problem is the fact that onclick call oMsg() inside Form? For example, when oMsg wascalled the Servlet wasn't called yet?

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. You must absolutely make sure that you are not attempting to get the results before the servlet has fully executed. That's why, in my code snippet, you see the "placeholder" code that expects the results from the servlet - - In my code snippet, the servlet doesn't run, so you just see the text at that point. You would get the same result. But, since you are getting `null`, something else is going on.

Comment: Scott, is there a way to "force" onclick to call the Function only after the Submit call the Servlet and that Servlet has fully executed? The only explanation to what is happen is that oMsg() is running before Servlet, right? By the way, when i ran your snippet copied with name loginServlet2 .jsp, that code called my Servlet. I can see that because the span of wMsgB has the msg "Teste OK!". "Teste OK!" is sended by Servlet.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. Even if the call was being made before the call to the servlet, you would still get the same results as my code snippet `<%=request.getAttribute("wMsg")%>` because that is the text of the `span` at that point in time. You say you are getting `null`, which means there is something else going on.

Comment: Scott, is there a way to see eventually a System.out.println that i could put in my Servlet? I'm trying to be sure that Servlet is running after oMsg(). As i've an Alert tag inside Function oMsg() i think that the Alert will pop up before my Servlet print a message. I'm running Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: @LucioTepeJr. I don't know anything about servlets. Sorry.

Comment: Scott, no problem, i'll search for something about that and i'll post here to update you about my issue. After all, there is a mystery here. But, you helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Scott, only to update you. I've found where the Tomcat log is. The log name is "tomcat7-stdout.YYYY-MM-DD where YYYY-MM-DD is the date when you're running your application. There is a log per day. So, i've checked my process and i pretty sure that onClick is running before Servlet. My alerts is been showed without any display of my Servlet in the log. Only after oMsg() is finished that i see in the log the displays from Servlet. I'm now trying to figure out how can i submit de form (call my servlet) before the onClick has been executed. Anyway, you helped me a lot. Thank you very much.