# Div innerText loses new lines after setting display to none

Tags: javascript, html, newline, contenteditable, innertext

While programming a custom WYSIWYG HTML based editor I came to this strange behavior.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/436kdv1b/1/)

One enters some text containing new lines in a div, which has `contentEditable` set to `true`.

At that moment `div.innerText` contains exactly the entered text including the new lines.

Then one sets `div.style.display = none` and re-checks the `div.innerText`: it is the same text, but the new lines are removed.

Why is that? Is there "standard behavior" for this case?

(Tested in both FF Developer Edition 89.0b3 (64-bit) and Chrome Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit))

=> Follow up
There is also another similar strange problem:

```js
var d = document.getElementById("divTest")

function setup() {
    d.innerText = "1\n2"
}

function log() {
    console.log(d.innerText)
  logChildren()
}

function logChildren() {
    console.log("Child nodes: ");
    d.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    console.log(node.toString());
  });
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="divTest"></div>
<input type="button" value="setContent" onclick="setup()"/>
<input type="button" value="log" onclick="log()"/>
```

Click on the `setContent` button and then on `log` button. The output is as expected:

```
1
2

[object Text]
[object HTMLBRElement]
[object Text]
```

Then click inside the input div. Press enter after the 2 to go to a new line, and press 3. One gets

```
1
2
3
```

in the div and one would expect to get the same in the `div.innerText`, but it is unfortunately:

```
1

2
3
Child nodes: 
[object Text]
[object HTMLBRElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

Why would 1 be a `[object Text]` but 2 and 3 `[object HTMLDivElement]` ? Why would there be empty line between 1 and 2? etc. ...

It does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Well, this is wild. What's interesting is, if you then set the display style back to `block`, the line breaks show up again! Feels like some sort of weird implementation bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `innerText` depends on whether or not the element is visible. As @Nisala noted in the comments, if you set the `display` attribute of the `div` back to `block`, the `innerText` contains your newline characters again.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

function performExperiment() {
  console.log(`innerText before style change: ${input.innerText}`);
  
  input.style.display = "none";
  console.log(`innerText after first style change: ${input.innerText}`);
  
  input.style.display = "block";
  console.log(`innerText after second style change: ${input.innerText}`);
}
```

```css
#input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter multiple lines of text into the box below, then click the button</p>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button onclick="performExperiment()">Experiment</button>
```

---

If we have a look at the `innerText` [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute), we see the first step of the behavior for the getter is defined as follows:

> 1. If [this](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#this) is not [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered) or if the user agent is a non-CSS user agent, then return [this](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#this)'s [descendant text content](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-descendant-text-content).
>
> > Note: This step can produce suprising results, as when the `innerText` getter is invoked on an element not [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered), its text contents are returned, but when accessed on an element that is [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered), all of its children that are not [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered) have their text contents ignored.

So when our `div` is not being rendered, we should expect that `innerText` returns the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of our `div`. Indeed, that is what we see.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

function performExperiment() {
  input.style.display = "none";
  console.log(`innerText: ${input.innerText}`);
  console.log(`textContent: ${input.textContent}`);
}
```

```css
#input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter multiple lines of text into the box below, then click the button</p>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button onclick="performExperiment()">Experiment</button>
```

---

So why are the newlines present in our `innerText` when the `div` is visible? The documentation continues:

> 2. Let *results* be a new empty [list](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#list)
> 3. For each child node *node* of [this](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#this):
>
> > 1. Let *current* be the [list](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#list) resulting in running the [inner text collection steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#inner-text-collection-steps) with *node*. Each item in *results* will either be a [string](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#string) or a positive integer (a *required line break count*).

In this case, `innerText` is ignoring `textContent` and is instead operating on the [`childNodes`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) list. Let's see what the value of that is for our `div`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

function performExperiment() {
  input.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    console.log(node.toString());
  });
}
```

```css
#input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter multiple lines of text into the box below, then click the button</p>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button onclick="performExperiment()">Experiment</button>
```

---

As you can see, pressing the `ENTER` key adds a newline to the content of our div by *adding a div* to the childNodes list of our `div`. Why this is the case is outside the scope of this question, but would make for a good question on its own.

If you're working on an in-page editor, the HTML spec [has a section containing best practices](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#best-practices-for-in-page-editors).

---

To recap:

If the `div` is visible, the `innerText` getter uses the `textContent` property of the `div`.

If the `div` is not visible, the [inner text collection steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#inner-text-collection-steps) are followed for each node in the `childNodes` tree and the results are concatenated together.

When computing the value of `innerText` for our `div`, the value of the `display` attribute matters because it determines whether the `textContent` property or the evaluation of the `childNodes` tree will be used.

---

Note: There's a little more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482962/14956277) by @Domino.

Comment: Super - thanks a lot - for both the detailed explanation/examples and the link to the documentation! I understand now, but can't see why they concatenate the nodes without the new lines (in the case of display:none)? 
The child nodes result as such only if the new lines exist in the first place - if there were not any new lines in the text, there would be only a single child node in the list (tried that in your last code snippet)
And they re-create the line-breaks from the list actually, but only in case of display:block.
So why the difference between display block vs none?

Comment: I believe the issue is that there *are no newlines*, just new `block`-level children of the `div` with inner text nodes containing the content from the new line. When the element is visible, `innerText` *injects* newlines between the text nodes from the tree which has the effect of resembling the effect of the `block`-level child nodes. When the element is not visible, `innerText` simply takes all the text nodes in the tree and concatenates them. I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes indeed - I have the same understanding. I just can not imagine why would one want to do that. If one has the function which "injects newlines", why not using it in all cases , regardless of the CSS representation, instead of checking the display property and then changing the logic, i.e. with or without newlines?