# Remove only text from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically generated HTML, for example:

```
const content = '<b>some <i>text</i><b>'
```

How can I get this content and remove last 2 letters, to get `<b>some <i>te</i><b>`? I'm getting this content via `el.innerHTML`. The main idea, I want to keep html how it is, and crop only text.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jquery?

Comment: @LiefdeWen no, plain JS.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript

Comment: @Stuart I don't want to remove html elements from string.

Comment: why don't you get the content using `el.textContent` instead?

Comment: !! That was a post to get you started, it seems that you haven't made an attempts to do this yet? Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

Using regex on HTML is... [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1377002).

An alternative method would be to create a new element, set its `innerHTML` to the string. Then update the text content of the `i` element.

```js
const content = '<b>some <i>text</i><b>';
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = content;
const i = span.querySelector('i');
i.textContent = i.textContent.substring(0, i.textContent.length - 2);
console.log(span.innerHTML);
```

Comment: The only issue with this is you need to know the element that contains the text you want to manipulate. So in the OP's example, the text is in an `<i>`. But since the OP said the HTML can be dynamic, I'm not sure that will always be the case. Still, this is a very good starting point.