# responsivevoice - I have to read the text inside the html element to the sound robot

Tags: javascript, html, api, text-to-speech, responsivevoice

responsivevoice .org
I couldn't do the text voice over service as I wanted.
There is no detailed explanation on the website.

I don't want to use < textarea > The example I want to use. I don't want to choose a robot. It should only speak Turkish Male. How should I do this?

```
<div id = "text-read"> one two tree four five </div>

<button onclick="responsiveVoice.speak('text-read');" type="button" value="Play">Play</button>
```

I want it to read the contents with the button.
Thank you for your interest

resources:
https://responsivevoice.org/api 
https://responsivevoice.org/text-to-speech-sdk/text-to-speech-play-button 
https://responsivevoice.org/text-to-speech-sdk/text-to-speech-widget

Comment: onclick="responsiveVoice.speak(text-read.textContent, 'Turkish Male')"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first parameter of the `speak` function represents the text to be spoken, the second one defines the voice:

```js
responsiveVoice.speak('bir, i̇ki, üç', 'Turkish Male');
```

If you want to get the text that is inside some HTML element, [you have to query it first, then get its text content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743966/3808452) and finally pass that to the function:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('text-read');
var text = element.innerText;
responsiveVoice.speak(text, 'Turkish Male');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    <!-- Turkish  Man Or Women Voice -->            
    var element = document.getElementById('#erkekoku');
    var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
    element.innerHTML = erkekoku;

    var element = document.getElementById('#erkekoku');
    var text = element.innerText;

    function manspeak(obj) {
    responsiveVoice.speak($('#erkekoku').text(), 'Turkish Male');
    };
    </script>

    <div id="erkekoku">Bu metni seslendirdim.</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="manspeak('article')">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>   
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script>
    ResponsiveVoice.setDefaultVoice("Australian Male");
</script>
</head>
<body>



<button onclick="speakText();" type="button">Play</button>

<script>
function speakText() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text-read').innerText;
  responsiveVoice.speak(text, 'Australian Male');
}
</script>


<div id="text-read">
<h1> Heading1. </h1>
<h2> Heading2. </h2>
<ul>
<li> List
<li> One,
<li> Two,
<li> Three,
<li> Four.
</ul>
<p> Paragrah. </p>
</div>
```