# Getting the whole content of a clicked <li> element

Tags: javascript, html, button

This is my HTML line:

```
<li onclick="return open_create_event_screen();">10</li>
```

I want to get the content of this < li > element (which is '10') through the JavaScript function (open_create_event_screen()) that opens once the < li > element is clicked.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What did you find when you googled: *"How to get element content in javascript"*?

Comment: @Reyno First you need to ask if he googled at all :)

Comment: I didn't find the right solution. I saw it's possible to check if an element was clicked but not to get its content.

Comment: @EzioMercer of course I googled it.. I have been looking for the answer but I didn't find my solution so I hoped I could find help here...  :)

Comment: @ofektal You need text content or with HTML tags?

Comment: @EzioMercer I need text content. Like the example I put in the question, I want to get the text content (in that case - '10').

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the pure text without HTML element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/how-to-get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-using-javascript)

Comment: No, because I need to know what element was clicked. And then, to take its text content.

Comment: I want to get the whole element and through it I'll get the text content.

Comment: This function doesn't include anything right now.

Comment: The receiving function gets an event object as parameter. You can access the clicked element with event.target and get the content with event.target.innerText.

Comment: @Onki Hara I tried it now, it works!! 
Thank you and all the others who helped me :) really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Old way, where we put inline events into our HTML.  The key is to pass `this` into the function, which is a reference to the element that was acted upon, you could also pass `event`, and determine the clicked element from the target property (two different approaches).

```js
const open_create_event_screen = (obj) => {
  console.log("opening create event screen");
  console.log(obj.innerText);
}
```

```html
<li onclick="open_create_event_screen(this);">10</li>
```

Here's a more modern approach, where our html is cleaner, and we do the work of assigning the event handlers in javascript.

```js
const open_create_event_screen = (obj) => {
  console.log("opening create event screen");
  console.log(obj.innerText);
}

const lis = document.querySelectorAll(".eventThing>li");
lis.forEach(li => 
  li.addEventListener("click", () => open_create_event_screen(li))
);
```

```html
<ul class="eventThing">
  <li>10</li>
  <li>20</li>
</ul>
```